# Is there a convention of formatting injected dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, code-formatting

### Angular JS Dependencies

Are there any commonly accepted conventions for how to format long lists of dependencies when using *inline bracket notation*?  After browsing through [github](http://github.com) and the [Angular JS Developer Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/), I haven't seen a consistent approach.

I'm not interested in what individuals think is best (sorry), but if there are **standard conventions** or **best practices** defined somewhere that I can't find.

---

### Examples

#### Standard

This is valid, but it extends to column 212.  It's also difficult to quickly compare the strings and the arguments.

```
angular.module('donkey', []).controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'someCoolService', 'anotherCoolService', 'somethingElse', function ($scope, $http, someCoolService, anotherCoolService, somethingElse) {
}]);
```

#### Somewhat better

It's still out to column 87, but it's easy to compare the strings and args.

```
angular
  .module('donkey', [])
  .controller('FooCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'someCoolService', 'anotherCoolService', 'somethingElse',
    function ($scope, $http, someCoolService, anotherCoolService, somethingElse) {
  }]);
```

#### Functional, but a little weird.

I'm inclined to use this one, since it's compact horizontally and allows for quickly commenting out dependencies.  However, it does seem a little weird.

```
angular
.module('donkey', [])
.controller('FooCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',
  'someCoolService',
  'anotherCoolService',
  'somethingElse',
  function (
    $scope, 
    $http, 
    someCoolService, 
    anotherCoolService, 
    somethingElse) {
}])
```

#### Extra Credit

Is there a way that satisfies JSLint's whitespace checks and also maintains the code collapse ability in Sublime Text 3?

Thanks!

---

## Resources

[Angular JS contributor coding rules](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-rules) make no mention of it.

[This best practice guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide) defers to Google, Crockford, etc.

Comment: I voted to close; because I don't think "Where do I put carriage returns in my code" is a programming problem.

Comment: @Reboog711, I'm asking if there is an accepted standard or best practice.  I've since read that [these buzzwords put people off](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354), but I still think it's a valid question.

Comment: All three of your iterations use identical code, except with carriage returns in different places. I don't think it warrants brain thought or discussion.  The formatting of code is usually irrelevant; ignoring any obsessive compulsive developer behavior.  But, best of luck w/ the question.

Comment: Thanks, @Reboog711.  The answer may very well be, "There is no convention."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that there is an accepted convention between the three *supported* methods for injecting dependencies within Angular.

That being said, I am currently working on a very large Angular project, and we consistently use the `$inject` syntax to define our dependencies. The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#methods_service) also seems to be trending in this direction.

So my advice would be this.

**Define All Your Dependencies As Objects**

```
var SomeService = function($rootScope, $http, $q){
  this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
  this.$http = $http;
  this.$q = $q;
};

SomeService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q'];

myModule.service('someService', SomeService);
```

This is going to make it a lot easier to reason about your code, and allow you to seperate out your services, directives, and controllers into different files.

**Except for very small applications, I would stay away from using the anonymous declarations and the array syntax for all of my dependencies.**

Comment: I'll accept the answer "There is no convention."  Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: This is pretty neat way to organize your modules/controllers/etc.

Comment: I'm slightly confused on how to implement this. Where do the individual pieces go structurally in an Angular app?